# Missing argument 1 error in laravel5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, model

I don't know why I'm getting this error because I believe that my code should work fine. Please see my code below:

*Controller*

```
public function view($id){
  $course = Course::find($id);

  return view('course.view', compact('course'));
}
```

*Model*

```
protected $fillable = ['deleted'];
```

*View*

```
@if($course->deleted == 0)
  <h2>Not Deleted</h2>
@endif
```

**Error:**

> Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::deleted(),
>   called in
>   .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
>   on line 2670 and defined  (View:
>   .../Courses/Resources/views/courses/view.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check it

```
@if($course->deleted() == 0)
  <h2>Not Deleted</h2>
@endif
```